# DNA replication, why complex

Tags: dna

When the DNA replicates, it first attaches RNA since the DNA polymerase can't attach DNA in the 3' end. Why the replication is happened this way? 
If the DNA polymerase can attach DNA from the 3', the replication process will be much simpler.
Is there a special reason for this?